# Mixing oldstylenums with strings

Tags: fonts, oldstylenums, latin-modern

I want to display the following string:

```
344F9DA1EA1859437077CCA38923C67797BDB8F6
```

Using `\oldstylenums`, but the alphabetic characters are messed up. Any ideas (using LaTeX and CM/CL fonts), without resorting to:

```
\oldstylenums{344}F\oldstylenums{9}DA\oldstylenums{1} ...
```

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,pdftex]{article} % define the title 

\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}
    \oldstylenums{344F9DA1EA1859437077CCA38923C67797BDB8F6}
\end{document}
```

Comment: *"I'm from Missouri, you've got to show me."* In other words, please provide a working minimal example that shows what exactly is "messed up".

Comment: Sure, I added it, but it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Sorry for being a little snippy -- I provided an answer and hope that it is helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest to use the [cfr-lm](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/cfr-lm.html) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[rm={oldstyle=false}]{cfr-lm}

\begin{document}

344F9DA1EA1859437077CCA38923C67797BDB8F6

\texto{344F9DA1EA1859437077CCA38923C67797BDB8F6}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, but that will make everything oldstyle... I'm looking to format just a specific block.

Comment: @Hugo: You didn't say so before. `;-)` Answer updated.