# Typeset year in old-style numbers with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

When I cite an entry in my bibliography (using style `authoryear-comp`) I would like the year typeset using old-style numbers. I have partially achieved what I want by redefining the bib macro `cite:labeldate+extradate` but it doesn't fully work (and makes me suspect I am fundamentally not going about this in the right way).

For example, below is a MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Thor2009,
    author  = {Thor, Alice Ursula and Smith, John},
    journal = {Some Journal},
    number  = {8},
    pages   = {123--456},
    title   = {A Very Important Paper},
    volume  = {79},
    year    = {2009}
}

@article{Thor2009b,
    author  = {Thor, Alice Ursula and Smith, John},
    journal = {Some Different Journal},
    number  = {8},
    pages   = {123--456},
    title   = {Another Very Important Paper},
    volume  = {79},
    year    = {2009}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% Style for years
\newcommand{\y}[1]{\oldstylenums{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\y{\printlabeldateextra}}}}


\begin{document}
    Hello \textcite{Thor2009,Thor2009b}.

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

When the above is typeset the citation contains the string "(2009a,b)". The year is typeset using old-style numbers, however the "a" (I think) also is typeset in this way which makes it appear as if it were in italics, and finally the ",b" (correctly) is not affected. What I want is for the year (and nothing else) to be set in old-style numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for date printing in `biblatex` is a bit ... unusual and scattered around many different places. It evolved quite a bit and the different requirements mean that it has grown quite complex.

The difficulty with the approach in the question is that the `extradate` label is also printed by the `\printlabeldateextra` command and so `\oldstylenums` would also apply to it.

Ultimately, the code that does the date typesetting lives in the `.lbx` file. If you want to change all years to old style numerals, you should probably attack there.

Unfortunately, the code is not exactly short and sweet.

The code below is taken from `english.lbx` ([ll. 24-51](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/476a0dad3146012955b1f1441ffbc8f1d015ef35/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx#L24)). If you are using other languages, you need to apply a similar redefinition for each language you use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\bibyearformat}{\oldstylenums}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#3}
         {\iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}
         {\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{,\space}}%
     \iffieldbibstring{#1}
       {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
       {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\bibyearformat{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkmonthzeros{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#3}
         {\iffieldundef{#1}{}{/}}
         {/}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\mkdayzeros{\thefield{#3}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{/}}%
     \iffieldbibstring{#1}
       {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
       {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\bibyearformat{\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibseasondateshort#1#2{%
    \mkbibseason{\thefield{#2}}%
    \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}%
    \dateeraprintpre{#1}\bibyearformat{\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibseasondatelong#1#2{%
    \mkbibseason{\thefield{#2}}%
    \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}%
    \dateeraprintpre{#1}\bibyearformat{\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Thor2009,
  author  = {Thor, Alice Ursula and Smith, John},
  journal = {Some Journal},
  number  = {8},
  pages   = {123--456},
  title   = {A Very Important Paper},
  volume  = {79},
  year    = {2009},
}
@article{Thor2009b,
  author  = {Thor, Alice Ursula and Smith, John},
  journal = {Some Different Journal},
  number  = {8},
  pages   = {123--456},
  title   = {Another Very Important Paper},
  volume  = {79},
  year    = {2009},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Hello \textcite{Thor2009,Thor2009b}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: All years in old style numerals.]

Currently, the code only applies old style nums for years. Months and days are left alone, one would probably change those to old style nums as well.

```
\newcommand*{\bibdatenumformat}{\oldstylenums}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
  \protected\def\mkbibdatelong#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\mkbibmonth{\thefield{#2}}%
       \iffieldundef{#3}
         {\iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}}
         {\nobreakspace}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\bibdatenumformat{\stripzeros{\thefield{#3}}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{,\space}}%
     \iffieldbibstring{#1}
       {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
       {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\bibdatenumformat{\stripzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibdateshort#1#2#3{%
    \iffieldundef{#2}
      {}
      {\bibdatenumformat{\mkmonthzeros{\thefield{#2}}}%
       \iffieldundef{#3}
         {\iffieldundef{#1}{}{/}}
         {/}}%
    \iffieldundef{#3}
      {}
      {\bibdatenumformat{\mkdayzeros{\thefield{#3}}}%
       \iffieldundef{#1}{}{/}}%
     \iffieldbibstring{#1}
       {\bibstring{\thefield{#1}}}
       {\dateeraprintpre{#1}\bibdatenumformat{\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibseasondateshort#1#2{%
    \mkbibseason{\thefield{#2}}%
    \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}%
    \dateeraprintpre{#1}\bibdatenumformat{\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
  \protected\def\mkbibseasondatelong#1#2{%
    \mkbibseason{\thefield{#2}}%
    \iffieldundef{#1}{}{\space}%
    \dateeraprintpre{#1}\bibdatenumformat{\mkyearzeros{\thefield{#1}}}}%
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me. Now I "just" need to understand the `.lbx` code!

Answer (score 4):

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{oldstyle}{\oldstylenums{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:labeldate+extradate}{%
    \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[oldstyle]{\printlabeldateextra}}}
```

or, if you need `hyperref`

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{oldstyle}{\bibhyperref{\oldstylenums{#1}}}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 But note that the `b` is not in the same style as the `a`

Comment: While this is arguably more `biblatex`-y in its execution than the code in the question (use of `\DeclareFieldFormat` and `\printtext` over the naked macro) it produces the exact same result as the MWE from the question in this instance, so it can't really be the expected answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should adjust the field format for `date` etc. via e.g.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\oldstylenums{#1}}
```

which is where the `biblatex` documentation says changes to fonts for individual fields belong.
Unfortunately there are several fields to set to get this right.  If have missed some please let me know.

[image: Sample output]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Thor2009,
    author  = {Thor, Alice Ursula and Smith, John},
    journal = {Some Journal},
    number  = {8},
    pages   = {123--456},
    title   = {A Very Important Paper},
    volume  = {79},
    year    = {2009}
}

@article{Thor2009b,
    author  = {Thor, Alice Ursula and Smith, John},
    journal = {Some Different Journal},
    number  = {8},
    pages   = {123--456},
    title   = {Another Very Important Paper},
    volume  = {79},
    year    = {2009}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{\oldstylenums{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{dateextra}{\oldstylenums{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{extradate}{\oldstylenums{\mknumalph{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labeldate}{\oldstylenums{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labeldateextra}{\oldstylenums{#1}}

\begin{document}

Hello \textcite{Thor2009,Thor2009b}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\DeclareFieldFormat{<datetype>date}` won't do anything useful. The `<datetype>` in the documentation is supposed to be a variable that takes can take the various 'date type prefixes' like `orig` (for `origdate`) or `url` (for `urldate`) etc. (`<datetype>` is empty for `date`.)

Comment: @moewe Ah, thank you for the clarification.  I'll drop the line from my code, rather than trying to chase all possible instances.

Comment: I think a problem with this approach is that it typesets the whole compound label using `\oldstylenums`. In some fonts (e.g., STIX; try adding `\usepackage{stix2}` to the preamble) only digits come out correctly (for example in STIX it looks like "(2009,)"). (Could this be fixed by writing a more sophisticated macro that typesets digits inside oldstylenums and leaves everything else unchanged?)

Comment: `\oldstylenums` is core LaTeX and specifically sets letters in math style.  `stix2` should respect this; you can partially fix this by passing the `notextcomp` option to the package, but you should report this as a package bug.   For near standard fonts you can use the `cfr-lm` package, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13455/15925  `fontspec` with `lualatex` would provide other possibilities.